# In Dlib how do I save image with overlay?

Tags: c++, dlib

I'm trying to modify Dlib's face detection example to save an image with detections to a file since I'm using a server without GUI. So far I have only figured how to save the image but not the overlay. How do I save both to the same file?

```
//win.add_overlay(dets, rgb_pixel(255,0,0));
save_png(img, "detected.png");
```

Comment: How to use draw_rectangle in c++, Please help

Comment: I have asked about it but It seems not got attention ..can u please tell me how did u saved image with overlay...You can also answer my question.[link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662894/how-to-save-resulted-face-landmark-image-in-dlib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [draw_rectangle](http://dlib.net/imaging.html#draw_rectangle) on the image before saving it.

Comment: what is the syntax to use `draw_rectangle`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `dlib::draw_rectangle()`

Example:

```
dlib::draw_rectangle(rect_image, rect, dlib::rgb_pixel(255, 0, 0), 1);
```

Comment: What's the syntax to use it in Python?