# How to save image with detection box in Dlib?

Tags: python, dlib

I'm trying to modify Dlib's train_object_detector example to save an image with the detection boxes to a file. How can I save the image with the overlay. After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762785/in-dlib-how-do-i-save-image-with-overlay/29767019#29767019), I did:

```
import os
import sys
import glob

import dlib
from skimage import io

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print(
        "Give the path to the examples/faces directory as the argument to this "
        "program. For example, if you are in the python_examples folder then "
        "execute this program by running:\n"
        "    ./train_object_detector.py ../examples/faces")
    exit()
faces_folder = sys.argv[1]


options = dlib.simple_object_detector_training_options()

options.add_left_right_image_flips = True

options.C = 5

options.num_threads = 8
options.be_verbose = True


training_xml_path = os.path.join(faces_folder, "training.xml")
testing_xml_path = os.path.join(faces_folder, "testing.xml")


# Now let's use the detector as you would in a normal application.  First we
# will load it from disk.
detector = dlib.simple_object_detector("detector.svm")

# We can look at the HOG filter we learned.  It should look like a face.  Neat!
win_det = dlib.image_window()
win_det.set_image(detector)

# Now let's run the detector over the images in the faces folder and display the
# results.
print("Showing detections on the images in the faces folder...")
win = dlib.image_window()
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder, "*.jpg")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)
    dets = detector(img)
    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
            k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))

    win.clear_overlay()
    win.set_image(img)
    win.add_overlay(dets)
    img1 = dlib.draw_rectangle(img,dets)
    outname = f + "_detected.jpg"
    #img1 = np.where(dets != 0, dets, img)
    io.imsave(outname,img1)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mas/dlib/python_examples/testing.py", line 74, in <module>
    img1 = dlib.draw_rectangle(img,dets)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'draw_rectangle'
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with using opencv you can do with `cv2.rectangle()`.

Instead of using `img1 = dlib.draw_rectangle(img,dets)` in your code, you can use:

```py
for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        print ("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
        cv2.rectangle(img, (d.left(), d.top()), (d.right(), d.bottom()), (255, 0, 255), 2)
```

This will draw rectangle over the original image.
You can save the image using `cv2.imwrite()` function:

```
cv2.imwrite(outname, img)
```

Comment: Is this also works if you want to extract the facial landmark prediction only (not with the image)?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a draw_rectangle Method in the Python API of DLib either. However, you can simply use the coordinates of the rectangle objects returned by the detector() Method to draw the detection boxes yourself, like so:
(using skimage polygon_perimeter)

```
from skimage import io
from skimage.draw import polygon_perimeter
...
for d in dets:
   rr,cc = polygon_perimeter([d.top(), d.top(), d.bottom(), d.bottom()],
                             [d.right(), d.left(), d.left(), d.right()])
   img[rr, cc] = (255, 0, 0)
...
io.imsave('imgname.jpg', img)
```